# Как определить что закрылось приложение? Firefox например?

Tags: linux, git, firefox

Нужно делать коммит профиля Firefox, каждый раз после его закрытия. Как понять что FF закрылся? Не буду я его в процессах постоянно мониторить. Потому что пользователь может включить машину, а браузер не запустить и чем то другим заниматься или же наоборот запускать Firefox по несколько раз в день.

Comment: сделайте свое приложение, которое будет запускать firefox. В этом случае, Ваше приложение будет получать управление, как только фаервокс закроется

Comment: Если Вы хотите держать копию профиля, возможно стоит рассотреть вариант firefox sync?

Comment: Какая разница КТО будет ждать, что FF закрылся? Никакой. Метка git не нужна -- выпилил.

Comment: @KoVadim возможно это тоже вариант))

Comment: @AK метка как раз таки нужна, здесь суть в том что бы гит подключить к профилю, не для бэкапа, а для управления. Например если пользователь захотел  бы то откатился на тот день когда у него стояли определенный набор расширений, закладок и паролей и т.п. А потом со временем он изменил что то и у него есть возможность вернуться в тот день. Вы можете сказать что сейчас есть контейнеры и альтернативные профили, но ведь так удобнее: в этой ветке у меня рабочий профиль, а в этой домашний без всяких там рабочих дополнений и т.п.

Comment: @АнтонСкородумов в firefox sync к сожалению есть лимит на определённое количество закладок (не помню конкретно какое, но есть). 
так что если вы любитель по папкам разложить все ваши закладки, то их не забэкапишь в firefox sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подход у вас неточный. Вместо того, чтобы детектить запущенный процесс Firefox -- лучше мониторьте, что Firefox держит открытым ваш профиль.

Вообще, профилей может быть несколько на компьютере, но запущенным будет только один.

Определить, что [профиль Firefox in use](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_in_use) можно по наличию или отсутствию файла:

- "parent.lock" (Windows),
- "lock" and ".parentlock" (Linux)
- ".parentlock" (Mac OS X)

Поскольку до компьютера с FF под linux доберусь только к вечеру, то сразу проверить информацию не могу, постараюсь позже дополнить ответ.

И ещё. Пока искал инфу -- наткнулся на [обсуждение](https://forum.mozilla-russia.org/viewtopic.php?id=54813) того, что эта фича сломалась и [фикс есть только для Windows](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=726759#c7).

Так что пока просто обозначаю направление, куда копать -- а до полноценного решения ещё далеко.

Updated. Эм. Смотрите, какая ситуация. На машине под Centos7 в профиле находится ВСЕГДА файл parent.lock - а файл lock находится только когда профиль in use.

Похоже, что поломалось только под win.

Мне кажется, вам в первую очередь нужно попробовать на своей системе посмотреть, как это у вас работает. Какой у вас дистрибутив Linux?

Comment: вообще то нет, одновременно можно только два запустить профиля. 
три и более - нельзя. 

один на основную лису, а второй параллельно на девелоп лису. 

но Вы правы в том что есть файлы которые находятся в профиле только когда он активен, например есть папка sessionstore-backups которая выполняет всем известную функцию (не сложно догадаться из названия). 

можно ее мониторить, но это всё равно получается активное ожидание. 

если же как то можно этого избежать - поправьте меня и направьте на истинный путь :)

Comment: дело всё в том что была как раз таки причина из-за которой все это потребовалось. 

был на машине установлен FF57 и пользователь решил установить ESR версию, это 52 кажется, то есть даунгрейд.

Comment: И все было бы ничего укажи он флаг "-p" в командной строке, создал бы себе новый профиль и все было бы в шоколаде. 
Но мы все люди и немного забывчивые иногда бываем. 
Он открыл 52 версию прямо из профиля 57-ой. 
А мозилла как раз надавно предупреждала что они внесли несовместимые изменения в новый профиль по дэфолту которые не будут восприниматься старыми версиями FF.

Comment: B итоге все закладки, настройки и т.п. исчезли навсегда. 
Потому что у стабильной версии должен быть только один активный профиль. Их может быть несколько, но активным только один. 

В то время как девелоп лиса может одновременно запускать два активных профиля. 
Ну один свой, а второй основной. 

Вот такое вот несчастье приключилось.

Comment: После этого мы подумали и придумали что гит как раз был бы кстати если бы профилем можно было управлять.  
Ну и как плюсом шло - это бэкапы, если даже ESR версия что и нарушит мы сможет сразу сделать чекаут на конкретный коммит.

Answer (score 7):

например, можно заменить вызов программы вызовом «обёртки».

1. получаете путь к исполняемому файлу:

   ```
   $ which программа
   ```
2. переименовываете его, добавив к имени, например, какой-нибудь суффикс:

   ```
   $ sudo mv /полученный/путь /полученный/путь.realprogram
   ```
3. а под исходным именем помещаете скрипт-обёртку такого примерно вида:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   # запуск исходной программы:
   /полученный/путь.realprogram
   # ваш код, который будет выполняться после
   # завершения работы исходной программы
   ```
4. не забыв добавить этому файлу биты исполнимости:

   ```
   $ sudo chmod +x /полученный/путь
   ```

Comment: И всё сломается при ближайшем обновлении фаерфокса :)

Comment: @andreymal а почему ломается?

Comment: @andreymal, нууу, если потребуется обработка и **такого** случая, то можно ведь и соответствующий вопрос задать на ru.so (улыбка)