# Linux, убить долгий процесс (по времени)

Tags: linux, debian, cron

Периодически в системе запускается некоторый конвертер. Он отрабатывает быстро (несколько секунд) и все ок.
Но бывает, что он остается висеть в процессах. В итоге за несколько дней таких процессов может висеть некоторое кол-во и все они занимают память.
Подскажите скрипт, который можно было бы поставить на крон и он бы искал процессы по имени висящие, допустим, более 5 минут в памяти и убивал бы их.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: подсказываю: запускайте не процесс, а ваш скрипт. который сначала убьёт предыдущий экземпляр процесса, а потом запустит новый: `pkill процесс; процесс`

Comment: Конвертер может быть запущен одновременно из разных мест. Можно записывать конечно все процессы и потом следить живы ли они через 5 минут, например. Но разве нельзя проще с помощью ps выбрать как-то такие процессы и прибить?

Comment: [обёртка на языке оболочки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/745988/178576) — это **гораздо** проще, чем реализация и управление следящим демоном (к чему вы и клоните). если вам надо несколько процессов держать, то создавайте для каждого процесса уникальный файл, содержащий внутри и в названии pid, и при старте обёртки убивайте те процессы, файлы для которых старше скольки вам там надо минут (файл при этом тоже удаляйте).